# start a web browser from my code in c linux

Tags: c, browser

I found a way using a Terminal Command for that purpose:
xdg-open http://www.google.com

But how can I do it from my code?
Thanks.

Comment: man system or man popen.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know C, but it seems like you just need to call said shell script via C. So after a quick google search (hint hint), you could probably call something along the lines of

```
system("xdg-open http://www.google.com");
```

Basically you just want a function that can execute a shell script

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it lets the OS decide what application to use to handle the link.  Also good luck in the mod elections.  Its funny that this helped me earlier today and then I saw you in the election.  Had to double take.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>   
int main()    
{  
    char *URL;   
    URL = "xdg-open http://google.com";
    system(URL);   
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the executable for Firefox (or Chrome, etc) is in your path, you can get away with:

```
system("firefox http://www.google.com");
```

If not, try:

```
system("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla\\Firefox.exe http://www.google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to include `stdio.h` and use the `system()` call to call `xdv-open`.

If you want to be able to change the url, try:

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main(int argc, char ** argv){

    char url[128]; //you could make this bigger if you want
    scanf("%s",url); // get the url from the console

    char call[256];
    strcpy(call, "xdg-open "); // web browser command
    strcat(call, url); // append url

    system(call);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdlib.h>   
int main()    
{  
    char *URL;   
    URL = "chromium http://localhost/image/index.php";        
    system(URL);   
    return 0;  
}
```